# Display datetime2(7) to time on gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hello i want to display the datetime2(7) that is coming from my db  `1900-01-01 02:15:00.0000000`  to `02:15 PM`  and also want that when the data is not coming from db i will print N/A. How this can be possible

I use this `<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("PICKTIME").ToString()).ToString("hh:mm tt")%>`

in above code if the value is coming NULL then its give me exception

So i use this

```
'<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("readyTime").ToString()) ? "N/A" : Eval("readyTime"))%>'
```

but problem is that it print `1900-01-01 02 :15:00` if value is not coming then `NULL`. But i want `02:15` if not any Value then `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why convert it to a date?  It is datetime that is padded with zeros, making it easy to parse with string functions.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("readyTime").ToString()) ? "N/A":Eval("readyTime").ToString().Substring(12,5)
```